# Webkit Javascript Causes Page Jumping

Tags: javascript, iphone, timer, webkit

Using this code

```
v=new Date();
var bxx=document.getElementById('bxx');
function t(){
    n=new Date();
    ss={time};
    s=ss-Math.round((n.getTime()-v.getTime())/1000.);
    m=0;h=0;
    if(s<0){
        bxx.innerHTML='<a ';
    }else{
        if(s>59){m=Math.floor(s/60);s=s-m*60;}
        if(m>59){h=Math.floor(m/60);m=m-h*60;}
        if(s<10){s="0"+s}
        if(m<10){m="0"+m}
        bxx.innerHTML=h+':'+m+':'+s+'<br>{name}</a>';
    }
    window.setTimeout("t();",999);
}
t();
```

Whenever t() is called, the page jumps to the top of the screen. Any ideas?

The {} are server parsed variables, but they should be causing any problem.

By jumping, I mean that the page, scrolled to the bottom, suddenly jumps to the top of the page

Comment: Have you tried this in multiple browsers? Please describe your element *bxx*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the jumping, but that code has a couple of issues:

1) Hopefully all of these variables are declared somewhere that you haven't shown? (If not, you're falling prey to the [*Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), which I'd recommend avoiding.)

2) This code:

```
bxx.innerHTML='<a ';
```

...is asking the browser to parse an invalid HTML fragment.

3) As is this code:

```
bxx.innerHTML=h+':'+m+':'+s+'<br>{name}</a>';
```

...as `h` and such are numbers, and so you end up with `1:23:45<br>name</a>`.

The `innerHTML` property cannot contain partial element tags, because it represents the entire content of an element, and elements can't cross over one another like that (the DOM is a tree, not a weave).

You'll want to modify the code so that it's always writing a fully-formed `a` tag to the `bxx.innerHTML` property, all in one go.

Once you do that, it *could* still cause some minor jumping, if the former content of the element has different dimensions than the new content. You can mitigate that with CSS (an inline-block element with width and height, etc.).